# JSON complex nested array sort using order

Tags: javascript, json, sorting

I have a complex nested JSON array and I want to sort it from inside and outside level using `itemsortorder` from outside level and `subitemnameorder` from.inside level

My given Array below

```
    id:1,
    "fruits":[
        {
        "itemid":1,
        "itemname":"Red Fruits",
        "itemsortorder":2,
        "subitems":[ {"subitemname":"Apple", "subitemnameorder":2},
                     {"subitemname":"Grapes", "subitemnameorder":1},
                     {"subitemname":"Berryberry", "subitemnameorder":3}
                   ]
        },
        {
        "itemid":2,
        "itemname":"Yellow Fruits",
        "itemsortorder":1,
        "subitems":[ {"subitemname":"Orange", "subitemnameorder":3},
                     {"subitemname":"Gua", "subitemnameorder":1},
                     {"subitemname":"Mango", "subitemnameorder":2}
                   ]
        }

    ],
    "Vegetable":[
        {
        "itemid":3,
        "itemname":"Red Veggies",
        "itemsortorder":2,
        "subitems":[ {"subitemname":"Onion", "subitemnameorder":2},
                     {"subitemname":"Ginger", "subitemnameorder":1},
                     {"subitemname":"Carrot", "subitemnameorder":3}
                   ]
        },
        {
        "itemid":4,
        "itemname":"Small Veggies",
        "itemsortorder":1,
        "subitems":[ {"subitemname":"pepper", "subitemnameorder":3},
                     {"subitemname":"halo", "subitemnameorder":1},
                     {"subitemname":"good", "subitemnameorder":2}
                   ]
        },
        {
        "itemid":5,
        "itemname":"Cool",
        "itemsortorder":3,
        "subitems":[ {"subitemname":"abc", "subitemnameorder":3},
                     {"subitemname":"pqr", "subitemnameorder":1},
                     {"subitemname":"kooi", "subitemnameorder":2}
                   ]
        }

    ],

    "avoid":[
    {
        "itemid":3,
        "itemname":"avoid Veggies",
        "itemsortorder":2,
        "subitems":[ {"subitemname":"Onion", "subitemnameorder":2},
                     {"subitemname":"Ginger", "subitemnameorder":1},
                     {"subitemname":"Carrot", "subitemnameorder":3}
                   ]
        }]
}
```

Avoid the avoid array part

Expected

```
   {  
      "filename":"Yellow Fruits",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"Gua",
            "subitemnameorder":1
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Mango",
            "subitemnameorder":2
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Orange",
            "subitemnameorder":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "filename":"Red Fruits",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"Grapes",
            "subitemnameorder":1
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Apple",
            "subitemnameorder":2
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Berryberry",
            "subitemnameorder":3
         }
      ]
   },
   ,
   {  
      "filename":"Small Veggies",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"halo",
            "subitemnameorder":1
         },
         {  
            "filename":"good",
            "subitemnameorder":2
         },
         {  
            "filename":"pepper",
            "subitemnameorder":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "filename":"Red Veggies",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"Ginger",
            "subitemnameorder":1
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Carrot",
            "subitemnameorder":2
         },
         {  
            "filename":"Onion",
            "subitemnameorder":3
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      "filename":"Cool",
      "children":[  
         {  
            "filename":"pqr",
            "subitemnameorder":1
         },
         {  
            "filename":"kooi",
            "subitemnameorder":2
         },
         {  
            "filename":"abc",
            "subitemnameorder":3
         }
      ]
   }
   ]
```

First it should take from fruits and sort accordingly then take from vegetables and follow

I have tried with filter and map but not working. Please help.

I tried below function pls look fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/qb2pueg7

Comment: Please add your expected output from the posted code here.

Comment: @Jack Bashford added buddy pls refer

Comment: @Kunal Mukherjee pls look fiddle what I tried

Comment: but without knowing the key name how you are going to maintain the order..."generic" solution will not follow this "First it should take from fruits and sort accordingly then take from vegetables"

Comment: @arpit Sharma can you post as an answer? I will look into it. It will be ok if use key. Updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you will be assigning the json to variable `data` so the code follows as below

```
let keysarr = Object.keys(data);
let temp = [];
  for(let i=0;i<keysarr.length;i++){
    if(keysarr[i]!=="id" && keysarr[i]!=="avoid"){
     let tempsortL1 = data[keysarr[i]].
      sort((a,b)=>a.itemsortorder-b.itemsortorder).map((item)=>{
                let retObj={};
              retObj["filename"] = item.itemname;
              retObj["children"]=item.subitems.sort((a,b)=>a.subitemnameorder-b.subitemnameorder); 
          temp.push(retObj);
          return retObj;});

 }
};
```

Your required array will come to `temp`. Sorry if you feel code is unformatted I tried to maintain not considering the keys in sorting.
Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pv2sLejc/
Also attaching the image of console[image]

Comment: Please make a fiddle with input and output

Comment: updated the answer Although I don't expect anyone on SO to be such demanding for a simple logic replacement. In the fiddle I used your own fiddle by replacing the last lines

Comment: It is array of objects in your output it is array of array. Also given data is an object. You are taken it as an array. Can you update accordingly?

Comment: in that case I think u may need to iterate JSON object

Comment: you seem to be quite an intresting person you made me write full code then you tested, suggested change requests.. only thing remaining is delivery pipeline just kidding :)